# Does "hardly as risky as" mean "almost safer than"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I have some trouble interpreting "hardly as...as...", such as in here:

> This method is hardly as risky as that one.

Does this mean "This method is almost safer than that one"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. This method is **hardly** as risky as that one.
> 2. This method is **not** as risky as that one.

Here, *hardly* is an emphatic negative (meaning ["not at all"](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/hardly)).  I don't think it means "almost" here.

Sentence 2 has the same basic meaning, but sentence 1 is more emphatic.

Answer (score 2):

It's not *"almost safer"*. Being *"almost safer"* sounds like it is **still riskier**, though not by much.

You can understand the whole sentence as "This method is **almost surely safer** than that one."

To interpret the sentence straightforwardly, ...
In speaker's opinion, the other method might have some risk, no matter how small, it is **very unlikely** that **this** method will be as risk as **that** method.